# Asking Entity Framework not to retrieve list of related entities before adding a new one to it

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, entity-relationship

Two scenarios:

I have Nodes and NodeDetails coming in in XML format. I cycle through the document, creating new Node entity, then adding NodeDetails to it, then saving them together by calling `db.SaveChanges()`. When I trace the calls, all I see are a bunch of insert statements: first for Node, then for NodeDetails.

In the second scenario, I have Posts and PostDetails. Posts are already stored in the database. So I retrieve a Post, analyze it, add PostDetails to it, and then save. When I trace the calls, I see a select from PostDetails table for this Post, and then I see inserts. The select part occurs when I reach a statement that says `post.PostDetails.Add(newPostDetail);`

Now, I do understand the reasoning here but I would like to somehow override it. Is there a way to tell EF not to retrieve the list before inserting?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `post.PostDetails.Add(newPostDetail)` method EF has load the `PostDetails` collection. EF does this lazy loading when you first access the property. This causes `select` statement to be issued.

You can avoid that if you are adding elements to the collection for the very first time.

```
post.PostDetails = new List<PostDetail>();
post.PostDetails.Add(newPostDetail);
```

Or you can directly add a new `PostDetail` to the context without adding it to the collection.

```
var postDetail = new PostDetail{ Post = post };
//populate other properties
db.PostDetails.Add(postDetail);
```